# How to resolve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException error in mule?

Tags: mule, jco

I'm using sap component in my project.

please find below is my SAP component sample code:

```
 <sap:connector name="SAP_Configuration" jcoAsHost="${sapbw.host}" jcoUser="${sapbw.user}"
                jcoPasswd="${sapbw.password}" jcoSysnr="${sapbw.instance}" jcoClient="${sapbw.client}" 
                jcoLang="${sapbw.language}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP"/>
```

I have added required sapidoc3 and sapjco3 jar files in build path. As I'm working on Windows OS, I included sapjco3.dll file, but still getting below error.

> ```
> ERROR 2017-10-06 16:32:32,849 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> + Failed to deploy artifact 'nol-integration-v1.1', see    +
> + below                                                    +
> ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifact [nol-integration-v1.1]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:38) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15) ~[tooling-support-3.7.0.jar:?]
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sap/conn/jco/JCoException
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>   at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:129) ~[spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.isLiteConfigurationCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:157) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassUtils.checkConfigurationClassCandidate(ConfigurationClassUtils.java:108) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:278) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
>   at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:172) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:95) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   ... 10 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.findClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:175) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader.findClass(MuleApplicationClassLoader.java:134) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at org.mule.module.launcher.FineGrainedControlClassLoader.loadClass(FineGrainedControlClassLoader.java:119) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.7.0.jar:3.7.0]
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
>   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
> ```

Comment: You might think you added that JAR to the build path; perhaps not.  This is a *runtime* error.  It looks like the JAR containing com.sap.conn.jco.JCoException is not in the runtime package or it's in the wrong place.  Check your package.  Native code?  That will be a problem too, unless you have the java.library.path JVM argument set properly.

Comment: I could see the jar files in build path, but not sure the exact reason behind the error.

Comment: Build path?  Are they in the JAR you deployed?  If not, Spring Boot won't find them.

Comment: I have added sapjco3.jar, sapidoc3.jar and sapjco3.dll files

Answer (score 1):

Please change the maven scope to "provided" for sapjco3 and then put sapjco3.dll and sapjco.jar inside tomcat lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

If a JCo class cannot be found it is either because the sapjco3.jar is really not in the class path or the JCo initialization failed, for example at loading its native library.

Did you choose the correct JCo native library fitting to your JVM (32-bit vs. 64-bit)? You need to install the 32-bit version of JCo if you are using a 32-bit JVM even if running on a 64-bit operating system.

I don't know Mule, but SAP recommends not to deploy the sapjco3.jar together with a Java application into an application server runtime environment. Because JCo's native library may be loaded only once, it is better to treat it as a system library, i.e. put it into the Mule startup classpath itself. Otherwise the startup of a second application, which would also contain the sapjco3.jar, might fail.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is mavenized then add this dependency to the POM:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
<artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
<version>3.0-RC02</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer here on **official Mule solution** :

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Maven-to-add-SAP-Connector-dependencies